# ConfigParser read() не видит изменения с write(open())

Tags: python

Я только начал изучать ConfigParser, ну и не обошлось без проблем. Итак, у меня есть 3 файла **Первый** - .py, **Второй** - .py, и **Третий** - .ini. В первом файле по нажатию кнопки я записываю по одной строчке в 2 секциях:

```
import configparser
from tkinter import *

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
opt = input()
val = input()
window = Tk()
def kakoyto_tam_def():
    config.read("database/giftcodes.ini")
    config.set("DEFAULT", opt, val)
    config.set("TIMER", opt, val)
    config.write(open("database/giftcodes.ini", "w"))
Button(command=kakoyto_tam_def).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Во втором каждую секунду изменяю цифры во второй секции на -1, и также записываю изменения. И если цифра после изменения равна 0, то удаляю строчку эту строчку в 2 секциях:

```
import configparser
from time import sleep

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
while True:
    delete = []
    for x in config["TIMER"]:
        config.read("database/giftcodes.ini")
        if x == 0:
            delete.append(x)
        config.set("TIMER", x, x - 1) # И да, я знаю что x это текст а не число, это просто для примера
        config.write(open("database/giftcodes.ini", "w"))
    for x in delete:
        config.remove_option("DEFAULT", x)
        config.remove_option("TIMER", x)
        config.write(open("database/giftcodes.ini", "w"))
    sleep(1)
```

Затем я запускаю 2 файла (не спрашивайте как), я ввел qwerty и 10, добавились 2 строчки в 3 файл, таймер их увидел, и запустил обратный отсчет на 10 секунд. Когда время достигло 0, таймер спокойно удалил эти 2 строчки, но во второй раз когда я ввел новые значения (uiop и 20) **(Я программу не перезапускал, там просто вместо input() был Entry)**, он добавил не 2 строчки (одну в DEFAULT, вторую в TIMER), а 4, новые и недавно удаленные. Я начал глобальное расследование и заметил, что в 1 файле метод read(), не замечает, что 2 файл удалил 2 строчки, только при перезапуске 1 файла он заметил изменения. Знатоки питона и ConfigParser'а спасайте

Comment: Если Вы пишете свой проект (а не встраиваетесь в уже написаный) забейте на ini юзайте yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашел решение. Просто после каждого раза когда я добавляю 2 строчки с первого файла, я сбрасываю переменную config до его изначального положения (**config = configparser.ConfigParser()**)

Answer (score 1):

```py
config.write(open("database/giftcodes.ini", "w"))
```

Открытый файл нужно не забывать закрывать. У вас файл непонятно когда вообще закрывается и до этого момента буфер может не сбрасываться на диск и изменения не зафиксируются. Лучше делать, наверное, так, чтобы файл закрывался автоматически по выходу из блока кода:

```py
with open("database/giftcodes.ini", "w") as f:
    config.write(f)
```

Comment: Не помогло, 1 файл все также не видит изменения с 3 файла